# Excluding the Data of Child Class Model From The Super Class Model in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have some models like this:

```
class Super(models.Model):
    attr1 = ...
    attr2 = ...


class Child(Super):
    child_attr1 = ...
    child_attr2 = ...
```

Now I when I do `Child.objects.all()`, it gives child objects only. However, when I do `Super.objects.all()`, it gives all the super and child objects. Is there a queryset like `Super.objects.exclude(...)` which I can use to get the objects of Super class model only?

Comment: Please try `Super.objects.exclude(id__in=Child.objects.all())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Super.objects.exclude(pk__in=Child.objects.all())
```

I use that but I don't know if other optimizations exist.